# Randomly change background image for multiple elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, background-image

I am trying to change the background-image of multiple elements with jquery. 
The elements are supposed to start with a randomly selected background-image and should then shuffle through randomly selected background-images every 2 seconds.

I have put together this vanilla javascript using other pieces of code that I found while searching for a solution, but I am running into the following problems:

1. My code only changes the background-image of the first element.
2. My code starts with a randomly selected background-image but then it just goes through the list of images in order instead of randomly choosing a new image every time it changes.
3. The *background-size* value is somehow not applied anymore after the background-image is changed.

Here is my code:

```js
var urls = [
'url(http://placekitten.com/g/150/150)', 
'url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/200)', 
'url(http://placekitten.com/g/250/250)',
'url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300)',
'url(http://placekitten.com/g/350/350)',
'url(http://placekitten.com/g/400/400)',
'url(http://placekitten.com/g/450/450)'
];
var active = Math.floor(Math.random() * (urls.length));
setInterval(function(){
    document.querySelector('.logo').style.background = urls[active];
    active++;
    if (active == urls.length) active = 0;
}, 2000);
```

```css
.logo {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/150/150);
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: background .5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="logo"></div>
```

And here is the same code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sublines/u94qLxpw/21/)

Please help me get to a jQuery version that fixes my issues.

Comment: The method `.querySelector` will return you the first element that will match the css selector you pass as string. To have all the dom elements matching with the selector you should use `.querySelectorAll`. Btw, I don't see any jquery code inside, it's just vanilla js.

Comment: I've tried using querySelectorAll but it did not work and now I get it. This isn't actually jQuery.. I'll rephrase my question then. Thanks!

Comment: The `querySelectorAll` will return a list of doms, you should use the `forEach` method to loop in all the returned doms.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

example:
```js
var highlightedItems = userList.querySelectorAll(".highlighted");

highlightedItems.forEach(function(userItem) {
  deleteUser(userItem);
});
```

Comment: Here is an update: https://jsfiddle.net/aabramya/xz8f6dyu/4/

Comment: Thanks @ArmAbramyan! The code does what I tried to achieve but I have since noticed how annoying it looks when all of the elements change at the same time. Could we achieve something where only one element will change at a time but it randomly chooses which element starts and which element changes next?

Comment: What about this? https://jsfiddle.net/aabramya/xz8f6dyu/9/

Comment: Hi @ArmAbramyan, thank you again! Can you also prevent that one element changes twice? I mean that when an element has changed the background-images it should have to be one of the other elements that changes next..

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/aabramya/xz8f6dyu/14/

Comment: Thank you so much again. Somehow the last element never changes the background-image. Did I just not wait long enough or can you confirm this?

Comment: You are welcome @JaschaGoltermann! Ah, it was my mistake sorry, if you didn't already, just change number 3 to 4 inside `Math.floor` function ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all items with the class `logo` and use `forEach()` to iterate over them like this:

```js
var urls = [
'url(http://placekitten.com/g/150/150)', 
'url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/200)', 
'url(http://placekitten.com/g/250/250)',
'url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300)',
'url(http://placekitten.com/g/350/350)',
'url(http://placekitten.com/g/400/400)',
'url(http://placekitten.com/g/450/450)'
];
var active = Math.floor(Math.random() * (urls.length));
setInterval(function(){
    let logos = document.querySelectorAll('.logo');
    logos.forEach(function(item) {
       item.style.background = urls[active];
       active++;
       if (active == urls.length) active = 0;
    })
}, 2000);
```

```css
.logo {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/150/150);
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: background .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="logo"></div>
```

Update: An additional requirement, as mentioned in the comments to this answer, is to select randomly one of the 4 elements with the class logo and change the background image of this one and iterate through all 4 elements randomly. This can be done as follows:

```js
var urls = [
  'url(http://placekitten.com/g/150/150)',
  'url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/200)',
  'url(http://placekitten.com/g/250/250)',
  'url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300)',
  'url(http://placekitten.com/g/350/350)',
  'url(http://placekitten.com/g/400/400)',
  'url(http://placekitten.com/g/450/450)'
];
var active = Math.floor(Math.random() * (urls.length));
setInterval(function() {
  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  document.getElementsByClassName('logo')[rand].style.background = urls[active];
  active++;
  if (active == urls.length) active = 0;
  //})
}, 2000);
```

```css
.logo {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/150/150);
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: background .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="logo"></div>
```

Update: As mentioned in the comments, it should be prevented that the same image gets randomly updated twice in a row. This is now handled by storing the last updated image in a data-attribute and change the random number in case it is the same as this data-attribute. In addition, there was an issue with `background-size: cover`. This was solved by changing `background` to `background-image`.

```js
var urls = [
  'url(http://placekitten.com/g/150/150)',
  'url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/200)',
  'url(http://placekitten.com/g/250/250)',
  'url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300)',
  'url(http://placekitten.com/g/350/350)',
  'url(http://placekitten.com/g/400/400)',
  'url(http://placekitten.com/g/450/450)'
];
var active = Math.floor(Math.random() * (urls.length));
setInterval(function() {
  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  if (rand <= 2 && rand == document.getElementsByClassName('logo')[0].getAttribute("data-changed")) {
    rand = rand + 1;
  } else if (rand == 2 && rand == document.getElementsByClassName('logo')[0].getAttribute("data-changed")) {
    rand = rand - 1;
  }

  document.getElementsByClassName('logo')[rand].style.backgroundImage = urls[active];
  document.getElementsByClassName('logo')[0].setAttribute("data-changed", rand);

  active++;
  if (active == urls.length) active = 0;
  //})
}, 2000);
```

```css
.logo {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/150/150);
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: background .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="logo"></div>
```

Comment: That was quick and this is great! But now I notice how annoying it looks when all elements change at the same time. Could we achieve something where only one element will change at a time but it randomly chooses which element starts and which element changes next?

Comment: Thats great! Just two things: 
1. The background-sise somehow still doesn't work. 
2. Can you also prevent that one element changes twice? I mean that when an element has changed the background-images it should have to be one of the other elements that changes next.
Thanks!!

Comment: @JaschaGoltermann Should the background size be the real size of the image or what do you mean with the background size wouldn't work?

Comment: No, it should just be background-size: cover. I have set this in the css but somehow it is not applied anymore after the background-image is changed..

Comment: @JaschaGoltermann The background-size: cover issue is solved here: https://jsfiddle.net/vrjdh8oa/

Comment: @JaschaGoltermann The issue with one element changing twice is now solved, I updated my answer again with a solution.

Comment: Thank you so much @matthias_h, this works great and is exactly what I had in mind!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213788/discussion-between-jascha-goltermann-and-matthias-h).